# Nesting then grouping objects into arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm attempting to convert an array that I get in this format:

```
data = [
    { name: 'Buttons/Large/Primary', id: '1:23' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Large/Secondary', id: '1:24' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Medium/Primary', id: '1:25' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Medium/Secondary', id: '1:26' },
    { name: 'Forms/Text', id: '2:1' },
    { name: 'Forms/Checkbox', id: '2:2' },
];
```

to an array in this format:

```
data = [
    {
        name: "Buttons",
        id: '1:23',
        components: [{
            name: "Large",
            id: '1:23',
            components: [{
                name: "Primary",
                id: '1:23'
            }, {
                name: "Secondary",
                id: '1:24'
            }]
        },{
            name: "Medium",
            id: '1:25',
            components: [{
                name: "Primary",
                id: '1:25'
            }, {
                name: "Secondary",
                id: '1:26'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Forms",
        id: '2:1',
        components: [{
            name: "Text",
            id: '2:1'
        },{
            name: "Checkbox",
            id: '2:2'
        }]
    }
];
```

My approach was to create arrays from each object in the original dataset by splitting the name property at '/', then nest them inside each other. This is what I have so far, which nests each item in the original array, but lacks grouping them together like my target format shows. Suggestions?

```
function nestItems(obj, path, value) {
    let component = {};
    let temp = component;
    for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        let component = temp;
        component.name = path[i];
        component.id = value;
        if (path.length - 1 === i) {

        } else {

            component.components = {};
            temp = component.components;
        }
    }
    obj.push(component)
}
let obj = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let path = data[i].name.split('/');
    nestItems(obj, path, data[i].id);
}
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your approach for splitting with `/`.

Here's my approach for using `reduce` to create a map and generating the final array:

```js
const data = [
    { name: 'Buttons/Large/Primary', id: '1:23' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Large/Secondary', id: '1:24' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Medium/Primary', id: '1:25' },
    { name: 'Buttons/Medium/Secondary', id: '1:26' },
    { name: 'Forms/Text', id: '2:1' },
    { name: 'Forms/Checkbox', id: '2:2' },
];

const map = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id } = curr;
  const [parent, sub, subSub] = curr.name.split('/');
  if (acc[parent]) {
    if (acc[parent][sub]) {
      acc[parent][sub][subSub] = { id };
    } else {
      acc[parent][sub] = { id };
      if (subSub) {
        acc[parent][sub][subSub] = { id };
      }
    }
  } else {
    acc[parent] = { id };
    if (sub && subSub) {
      acc[parent][sub] = {
        id,
        [subSub]: { id }
      };
    } else if (sub) {
      acc[parent][sub] = { id };
    };
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(map).map(parentName => {
  const { id: parentId, ...subs } = map[parentName];
  const parentObj = { name: parentName, id: parentId };
  parentObj.components = Object.keys(subs).map(subName => {
    const { id: subId, ...subSubs } = subs[subName];
    const subObj = { name: subName, id: subId };
    if (Object.keys(subSubs).length) {
      subObj.components = Object.keys(subSubs).map(subSubName => ({ name: subSubName, id: subSubs[subSubName].id }));
    }
    return subObj;
  });
  
  return parentObj;
});

console.log(result);
```